# React native IOS notification service options

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I currently have an Android app which uses a Foreground service with an MQTT client to receive/create time sensitive notifications when the app isn't active. The business demand is that the user will receive a notification within 30 seconds after the event is created on the server.
Now, I have received a business request to port the app to IOS. I don't have any experience in IOS apps so I started doing some research into the world of Apple to see if it supports the current setup.
For what I have found so far, it doesn't.

So, my questions are:

1. Is long running processes possible in IOS, can I have a background MQTT listener like I have in Android?
2. What is the predominant solution for sending time sensitive data to both Android and IPhone? Firebase?

Local solutions (like MQTT) are preferred.

Comment: 1. No. 2. use push notifications (firebase messaging is one wrapper for push notifications but there are others or you can go direct).  You can use [local push connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/local_push_connectivity) but a lot more work is required to set it up compared to just using APNS.